# How to stream partially in react-native-video?

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am using node backend to provide mp4 video to be streamed.
this code is returning the video as a chunk.

```
app.get('/video', (req, res) => {
    i++;
    const range = req.headers.range;
    if (!range) {
        res.status(400).send("Requires Range header");
    }
    else {
        console.log(`Range = ${range}`);
    }

    // get video stats
    const videoSize = fs.statSync(videoPath).size;

    // Parse Range
    // Example: "bytes=32324-"
    const CHUNK_SIZE = 10 ** 6;
    const start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, ""));
    const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, videoSize - 1);

    // Create headers
    const contentLength = end - start + 1;
    console.log(`video hit (${i}). chunkSize=${CHUNK_SIZE}. start = ${start}. end = ${end}. contentLength = ${contentLength}, videoSize = ${videoSize}`);
    const headers = {
        "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
        "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
        "Content-Length": contentLength,
        "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
    };

    // HTTP Status 206 for Partial Content
    res.writeHead(206, headers);

    // create video read stream for this particular chunk
    const videoStream = fs.createReadStream(videoPath, { start, end });
    // console.log(videoStream);

    // Stream the video chunk to the client
    videoStream.pipe(res);
});
```

And I use react-native-video for streaming the video.

```
<Video
source={{
    uri: this.state.source.uri,
    type: 'mp4',
    headers: {
        'range': bytes=0-'
    }
}}
```

But it stopped after the first chunk is played. How can I load the next chunk?
I tried setting the headers range more than 0 to try loading the next chunk like this.

```
headers: {
    'range': 'bytes=1000-'
}
```

The backend is called properly,
but it give an error on the front-end

```
{"error": {"extra": -2147483648, "what": 1}}
```

And actually, I found the code to return video as a chunk while searching how to stream a video. But I don't get what's the point of using the chunk since react-native-video can just stream from direct url. Can anyone explain whether I should just use direct url or keep using the chunk method and looking for the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was following this tutorial to set up the NodeJs Express streaming https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNQYwonNigw . I think it was the same resource you used. It is working fine for me.

Make sure you videoPath variable is pointing to the right resource (you didn't define videoPath on your code).

On react-native I have:

```
<Video source={{
  uri: this.state.source.uri,
  type: 'mp4',
  headers: {
    'range': 'bytes=0-'
  }
}}/>
```

In your code you were missing ' at the beginning of bytes-0.

I don't need to set up the range requested on react-native. This seems to be handled automatically by react-native-video. When I press a different time on the video it loads it correctly. It also plays the full video, not only the first chunk.

I get the error `error: {extra: -2147483648, what: 1}` when the nodejs server is not running. Start it.